# Changing line colours in polar chart

Tags: mschart

I have a chart with a number of series each of which have the `ChartType` set to `Line`. I am controlling the colours of the lines by setting the `Color` property of individual points in each series. `Points(1).Color` controls the colour of the line joining the first two points (0 and 1), `Points(2).Color` the next line, etc. 
`Points(0).Color` has no effect.

This all works fine, but if I change the `ChartType` to `Polar`, all the colours are now wrong. It appears that now `Points(0).Color` controls the colour of the first line, `Points(1).Color` the second line etc.

This is really annoying. Obviously I can alter my code that sets the colours to add/subtract 1 to each Point index number, but it means I have to go through and re-colour every point in every series in the whole chart when I switch from one chart type to the other.

I'm guessing this is just down to how the individual chart types are implemented, but I just wondered before I go ahead and write the code to redo the colouring when the chart type is switched, if there might be some setting somewhere that controls this, or another trick to make this work.

I tried setting `IsReversed` on the `XAxis` but that has no effect on the colours for the Line chart, and no effect at all on the Polar chart.

Comment: You could try playing with the `Palette`, but I think that is `Series` based, not `Point` based.  It's also zero based.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed that!. I did always wonder why in a Line chart the color of a point is the incoming instead of the outgoing segment. So adding recoloring code seems to be the way to workaround.. - Instead you could separate the polar and line series altogether and enable disabable one gropup or the other.

Comment: For my particular application there tend to be blocks of points within each series with the same colour, so I was able to resolve it by splitting these off into individual separate series. That way I can just set the one colour for each series rather than per point.

Comment: @Baddack - There is a Series.Palette property which overrides Chartarea.Palette, so you could perhaps use a custom palette with one entry for each point and add/remove a dummy colour at the start when switching chart types. I may have a play with that idea.

Comment: Good to know!  That's why I like SO, I learn new things everyday.  Glad you were able to come to a solution.